# how to select parts of a shape in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select, borders

I have to have a Shapefile of France of the bigger regions: Ile-de-France, Bretagne, etc. and that is already included in my shape. But its only shown the Arrondissements (smaller regions) in France and their borders. 
How can I just show the borders of these bigger regions only?

[image: Here you can see the shape: Nom_CHF = Name of the smaller region, Nom_region = Name of the bigger region.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.  One is to set the style of your polygons to 'categorised' based on the region.  You will possibly want to set the border to 'no pen'.  Alternatively dissolve your data based on the larger regions.